# Open New Opera Browser Window When Clicking Shortcut

Tags: opera

I have Opera 39 installed on Windows 7.

When I click the icon on my taskbar (which points at launcher.exe with no arguments) a new tab in an existing Opera window.

I would like a new window to open instead.

Is there any way to tell it to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it. Right click on the shortcut icon, select properties, go to the "Shortcut" tab, and add `--new-window` at the very end of the line, so it looks something like:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\launcher.exe" --new-window`